# Error Conversion from string "Removed" to type 'Double' is not valid. for no reason

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a program in VB.Net and receiving the error above when I'm not even trying to convert anything into a double. In fact, I've removed any code associated with this string (it is from my.settings) and I still receive this error.

Originally, the user is asked for a password, and it is then stored in this setting. The password I chose contained a special character and numbers. Now whenever I debug my program, I receive this error in visual studio and I cannot get past it. How do I fix this? This is extremely frustrating.

I've even attempted to clear the strings with my.settings.reset on load and still I receive this error.

The error is receive in the Application.Designer.vb on this line:

```
Me.MainForm = Global.ProjectName.Form1
```

Stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
at Bitcoin_Multisig.Bitcoin..ctor() in D:\Documents\Coding\Projects\Bitcoin Multisig\Bitcoin Multisig\Bitcoin.vb:line 3
at Bitcoin_Multisig.Form1..ctor() in D:\Documents\Coding\Projects\Bitcoin Multisig\Bitcoin Multisig\Form1.vb:line 2
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: How do I get that? Sorry, it's been awhile since I've programmed.

Comment: In the error details in the popup.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/P9UwYk1.png I'm unsure if this is what you were looking for...sorry if it isn't.

Comment: Check the InnerException stack trace, and use the down arrow to see the full stack.

Comment: The stack trace says: "at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)" Also here is the rest: http://i.imgur.com/CVYsmlG.png

Comment: What's the entire inner stack trace?  (please edit your question)

Comment: I believe I added the correct stack trace. Sorry if I haven't.

Comment: Look at Bitcoin.vb:line 3.

Comment: I figured it out, I guess I was doing some weird string editing. Thanks for all the help and sorry for being such a pain...I feel dumb now.

Comment: If you solved the problem, then you should post it as an answer and accept it (e.g. were you passing in an invalid value that couldn't be converted?). Then others can learn from your mistake(s). You're only dumb if you keep repeating them. :)